# Installation problem - bootlogo

Tags: software-installation

I have problem with installation. When I start my computer it shows me text:

```
Loading bootlogo...
```

After a few minutes it shows:

```
EDD: Error 1000 Reading sector 352846
```

Comment: [...]Edd is way for very old BIOS to boot from disks that are larger than 32Gb.[..] How old is your computer?

Comment: After it shows loading bootlogo try press f10, f12 or whatever is your multiboot option. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

EDD is short for Enhanced Disk Drive Services and comes with the [BIOS interrupt INT 13H](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H). So without this extention your BIOS can only address approx. 8GB. When EDD is activated within grub it sometimes seems to introduce the problem you described. So you can disable it by adding `edd=off` to grub's `menu.lst` or add it directly to the grub commandline. To my knowledge it is safe to add this line. This should not introduce other problems (in some corner cases the font during boot is very large).