# My Ubuntu installation process is stuck during setup

Tags: system-installation

Trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.2, I highlighted `Install Ubuntu` and pressed <kbd>enter</kbd>. It became unresponsive and printed this error message:

```
EDD: Error reading sector 750247                             
EDD: Error reading sector 753811      
EDD: Error reading sector 736286                                              
EDD: Error reading sector 750246   
Booting Kernel Failed: Invalid argument
```

My laptop is a **Sahara N1356**
**Pentium M** processor
**120 GB** HDD
**1 GB** RAM

The original OS was windows vista

Comment: What do you mean by "home page"? What error message? Please edit your question and provide relevant information like the aforementioned questions and also post your hardware specs and the Ubuntu release you're trying to install.

Comment: Check the sum of your iso and tell us the error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installation problem - bootlogo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92631/installation-problem-bootlogo)

Comment: Not really his is not for the setup

Comment: @Mitch Could you please rule out bad hard disk, use a live session and benchmark it with Gnome-Disks and see if that's it.